# Parsing data leaves data out of the original file when importing

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro that parses data from a txt file and imports them to excel. On my code I include that each item will be registered as an attribute after the 5th or 6th comma respecitvely.

From my execution, I manage to parse the first item of the data but there are multiple items after the 5th or 6th comma that are not properly parsed.

I have tried inserting further if statement of parsing data after 15 or 16 commas but that doesn't do the trick therefore I am on a dead end.

```
Option Explicit
Public TXTFile As String, varTXTFileName As Variant, Beginningwrk As Variant

Private Sub OpenTXT()
    'This asks for text file to use
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

   
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "TXT Files", "*.txt?", 1 
        .Title = "Choose TXT File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False    
        If .Show = -1 Then
            TXTFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            varTXTFileName = Mid(.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1, Len(.SelectedItems(1)))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End With
    
  
    Workbooks.Open TXTFile
    Workbooks(Beginningwrk.Name).Activate
End Sub

Function ReadTXT() As Collection
        
    Dim lstRow As Integer, DataRng As Range, item As Range
    
    
    Set ReadTXT = New Collection 'Reads the txt file.
    Workbooks(varTXTFileName).Activate
    lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   
    
    Set DataRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lstRow, 1))  'get data
    With DataRng
        For Each item In DataRng
            ReadTXT.Add item        
        Next item
    End With
  
End Function

Sub ImportTXT(Optional fileName As String = "")

    'Beginning of the process -- Select text file to import data from
    Dim TXTData As Collection, shiftData As Collection, shiftEventsData As Collection
    Dim i As Integer, rowCnt As Integer, shiftVal As Integer, e As Variant
    Dim splitLine() As String, sEvents() As String, cleanStr As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set TXTData = New Collection
    Set shiftData = New Collection
    Set shiftEventsData = New Collection
    Set Beginningwrk = ThisWorkbook
    
    If (fileName = "") Then
        OpenTXT  'open txt file
    Else
        TXTFile = fileName 'drag drop
        varTXTFileName = Mid(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "\") + 1, Len(fileName))  '
        Workbooks.Open TXTFile
        Workbooks(Beginningwrk.Name).Activate
    End If
    
    If (TXTFile = "") Then Exit Sub
    Set TXTData = ReadTXT 'got data
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add   'setting attribute that will add a new workbook to a new excel
    wb.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Data Extracted"  'add new sheet named as ...
    Sheets("Data Extracted").Select  'select that new sheet to import data on
    
    'create header row
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = "Code"
    Cells(1, 3).Value = "Date"
    Cells(1, 4).Value = "Start"
    Cells(1, 5).Value = "End"
    rowCnt = 2                      'Setting the count of rows to 2 because on line 1 there is already a header row.
                                    

    For i = 2 To TXTData.Count 'add data to table  'skip first header line
        If (TXTData(i).Value <> "") Then
            'this is a date skip it                     'the txt file first item is the date that the file got exported which we do not need.
            splitLine = Split(TXTData(i).Value, ",")    'setting attribute that will split on every comma.
            If (UBound(splitLine) > 0) Then
                If (splitLine(5) <> "Off") Then
                    'this employee didn't have attributes therefore skip
                    Cells(rowCnt, 1).Value = splitLine(1) + " " + splitLine(0)
                    If (splitLine(5) <> "") Then                                'After first item is recorded, code checks after 5 spaces if there are attributes.
                        Set shiftData = ExtractCode(splitLine(5))               'Setting a variable that will extract items after 5 blank spaces.
                        For shiftVal = 1 To shiftData.Count Step 4              'imports data according to the desired output sample.
                            Cells(rowCnt, 2).Value = shiftData(shiftVal)
                            Cells(rowCnt, 3).Value = shiftData(shiftVal + 1)
                            Cells(rowCnt, 4).Value = shiftData(shiftVal + 2)
                            Cells(rowCnt, 5).Value = shiftData(shiftVal + 3)
                        Next shiftVal
            
                        rowCnt = rowCnt + 1 'After all items are recorded, move to next row
                        Set shiftData = Nothing
                    End If 'splitline 5
                    
                    
                    
                    'Needs to be modified
                    If (UBound(splitLine) > 5 And splitLine(UBound(splitLine)) <> "") Then
                        sEvents = Split(splitLine(6), ";")
                        For Each e In sEvents
                            cleanStr = Trim(Replace(CStr(e), """", ""))
                            If (cleanStr <> "") Then
                                Set shiftEventsData = ExtractCode(cleanStr)
                                Cells(rowCnt, 1).Value = splitLine(1) + " " + splitLine(0) 'name
                                For shiftVal = 1 To shiftEventsData.Count Step 4
                                    Cells(rowCnt, 2).Value = shiftEventsData(shiftVal) 'code
                                    Cells(rowCnt, 3).Value = shiftEventsData(shiftVal + 1) 'date
                                    Cells(rowCnt, 4).Value = shiftEventsData(shiftVal + 2) 'start
                                    Cells(rowCnt, 5).Value = shiftEventsData(shiftVal + 3) 'end
                                Next shiftVal
                            End If 'cleanStr
                        Next e
                    End If 'splitline 6

                End If 'splitline 5 not off
            End If 'splitline count
        End If
    Next i
    
    'autofit columns
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Beginningwrk.Activate 'return to first workbook
   
    Workbooks(varTXTFileName).Close 'close txt file
End Sub

Function ExtractCode(EmpCodeTime As String) As Collection
    
    Dim parseData() As String, item As Integer, temp As String, code As String, testdate As Date
    Dim time As Boolean, dItem As Integer
    Set ExtractCode = New Collection
    time = False                            'setting to False so we can break the start and end time accordingly.
    parseData = Split(EmpCodeTime, " ")     'Will split time so it can be recorded to start and end times.
    
    For item = 0 To UBound(parseData)
        temp = Replace(parseData(item), """", "") 'strip quotes from data
            
        If (time = False And (RegexIsDate(temp) = True) And (Len(temp) > 8)) Then
            ExtractCode.Add code
            testdate = CDate(temp)          'this is a date
            ExtractCode.Add CDate(temp)
            time = True                     'determine when reached time values
            dItem = item
        ElseIf (time And item = dItem + 1) Then
            ExtractCode.Add temp + Mid(parseData(item + 1), 1, 2) 'AM is in next array location
        ElseIf (time And item = dItem + 3) Then
            If (item = UBound(parseData)) Then
                ExtractCode.Add temp '4:00PM
            Else
                ExtractCode.Add temp + parseData(item + 1) '4:00 PM --when PM is in next array location
            End If
        Else
            code = code + " " + temp
        End If
    Next item
        
End Function


Private Function RegexIsDate(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim regexOne As Object
    Set regexOne = New RegExp
    
    regexOne.Pattern = "[0-9]"
    regexOne.Global = True
    RegexIsDate = regexOne.Test(Left(s, 1))
    
End Function

Public Sub ExtractData()
    
    ImportTXT   
End Sub
```

Comment: As no one has your data and you just posted a ton of code: How are we supposed to help you? Can you give at least an example of your input data? Have you debugged your code (execute it step by step) to see where it fails?

Comment: Difficult to make suggestions with so much code, and with no examples of the type of lines you're having problem parsing.